# Any VM software have a virtualized WiFi adapter?

Tags: wireless-networking, virtual-machine

I'm looking to brush up on my Windows Native WiFi API knowledge but I don't want to use BootCamp. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Most virtualization platforms use virtual switches to connect to the host machine. So, even if the host is using wifi, the guest uses a virtual ethernet 10/100/1000. This cuts down on a lot of headaches and keeps you from having to authorize the host and the guest.

The best suggestion I can give you to access a wifi directly would be to directly connect the wifi device to the VM. I don't think you could do this with the built in wifi from the host, but I'm pretty sure you could get a USB wifi and directly connect it to the VM. Then you could directly access the hardware from inside the VM.

Comment: Ah, a USB WiFi device. That's a great idea!

Comment: Xen can do PCI passthrough so could pass a onboard wifi card.

Comment: @user1144712 -Kismet if you will...